# Single thread code is much slower than serial code for the exact same function

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance

So I'm trying to do some multi-threading using windows threads. The problem I'm facing is that the exact same function call is much faster in the serial case(7 times!) than the single thread case. While I was looking into whether this was due to cache utilization issues, I saw some quick numbers in the task manager. In the serial case, the non-paged kernel memory used is 2793 MB. In the single thread case, this number rises up to ~3100MB. My suspicion is that in the single thread case, the thread that is spawned is on another processor and all the extra time is spent on moving data into the thread's memory. My question is 2 fold:

1. I don't exactly know what the non-paged kernel memory usage indicated on the task manager means, but given the described behavior, does it support my suspicion? Is there a better way to measure cache misses on windows(wish Valgrind worked on Windows :/)
2. If not, what else can cause this issue? The code paths to the function are exactly the same. The results from the function are exactly the same and there are no critical sections/mutexes or heap memory allocations inside. This has me stumped!

I'm unable to show any substantial source code, but the code path is something like this:

```
FunctionBeingProfiled() {
    point* p1 = globalPointArray[0];
    point* p2 = globalPointArray[1];
    point* p3 = globalPointArray[2];

    if (PointsAreProtected(p1, p2, p3)) {
          return false;
    }

    linesegment lseg(p1, p2);

    // The following 2 calls read from global data structures populated before this call is first encountered

    tetrahedron tet = FindFirstTet(&lseg); // Reads from a hash table

    EdgeIntersectionTest(&lseg); // Basically takes the given lseg and finds all the intersections from a global vector of line segments

    DoVolumeTest(&lseg, &tet); // uses only the passed in lseg and tet

    DoShapeTest(&lseg, &tet); // uses only the passed in lseg and tet
}

FuncA() {

if (serial) FunctionBeingProfiled();

if (parallel) {
    _beginthreadex(..); // This calls FunctionBeingProfiled
}

}
```

Comment: You should show real code. We can't debug hypothetical code.

Comment: working on putting up more substantial code

Comment: What is "serial code" anyway? _All_ code is run on a thread, and by default your program has one thread.

Comment: By serial code I mean I don't start any threads. Only 1 process executes the code. In the 1 thread code, I start a thread from the parent process using _beginthreadex that then calls FunctionBeingProfiled(). The reason I am testing single thread performance first is because the performance is even worse when I use multiple threads.

Comment: For anybody still interested in this, I have some new information. I forced the whole application to use only 1 CPU. This reduced the slowdown from 7 times to 3 times. So it looks like it was a cache issue. I'm yet to figure out why the 3 times slowdown is still occuring

Comment: It will be better to add [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can compile and run it.